# spring data jpa views

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i'm working on spring boot project with oracle and hibernate and spring data jpa!
i need a view to solve some problem in my app.
when i run query in native mode in Database console in intellij or JPQL console,it works fine!!
but when i use it with spring data like below shows,it returns this error:

**ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**

//JPQL-Console thats work fine!

```
select u.codUnitcodeUnts as codUnitcodeUnts, u.codUseridPstme as codUseridPstme from OcmChartUnitPostPstmeViw u 
where lower(trim(u.codCodeChrt))=lower(trim(:chartCode)) and upper(trim(u.codUnitcodeUnts)) in ('GAP','CIT') 
            and u.flgIsmanagerPost=true and u.staPoststatePost='ACTIVE' 
            and u.staMemberstatusPstme='ACTIVE'
```

//jpa Repository

```
 @Query(value = "select u.codUnitcodeUnts as codUnitcodeUnts, u.codUseridPstme as codUseridPstme " +
            "  from OcmChartUnitPostPstmeViw u " +
            "where lower(trim(u.codCodeChrt))=lower(trim(:chartCode)) " +
            "and upper(trim(u.codUnitcodeUnts)) in (:unitCodes) " +
            "and u.flgIsmanagerPost=true and u.staPoststatePost='ACTIVE' " +
            "and u.staMemberstatusPstme='ACTIVE'")
```

//Entity

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "OCM_CHART_UNIT_POST_PSTME_VIW", schema = "OCM", catalog = "")
public class OcmChartUnitPostPstmeViw implements Serializable {
    private String codCodeChrt;
    private String desChartnameChrt;
    private String staChartstatusChrt;
    private Long chartsId;
    private Long orgsOrgsId;
    private String txtUnitlableChrt;
    private String txtPostlableChrt;
    private String txtJoblableChrt;
    private Boolean flgIsprimeryaChrt;
    private String codUnitcodeUnts;
    private String staStatusUnts;
    private Long untsUnitsId;
    private Long chrtChartsId;
    private String desUnitdescUnts;
    private Long untyUntypeId;
    private Time datStartdateUnts;
    private Time datEnddateUnts;
    private Long unitsId;
    private String namLdapgroupUnts;
    private String codAreacodeUnts;
    private Long numSortUnts;
    private Time datStartdatePost;
    private Time datEnddatePost;
    private String staPoststatePost;
    private Long jobsJobsId;
    private String desPostdescPost;
    private String codPostcodePost;
    private Boolean flgIsmanagerPost;
    private Long postsId;
    private String namLdapgroupPost;
    private Long postPostsId;
    private String codUseridPstme;
    private String staMemberstatusPstme;
    private Time datStartdatePstme;
    private Time datEnddatePstme;
    private Long postmemId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "COD_CODE_CHRT")
    public String getCodCodeChrt() {
        return codCodeChrt;
    }

    public void setCodCodeChrt(String codCodeChrt) {
        this.codCodeChrt = codCodeChrt;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DES_CHARTNAME_CHRT")
    public String getDesChartnameChrt() {
        return desChartnameChrt;
    }

    public void setDesChartnameChrt(String desChartnameChrt) {
        this.desChartnameChrt = desChartnameChrt;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "STA_CHARTSTATUS_CHRT")
    public String getStaChartstatusChrt() {
        return staChartstatusChrt;
    }

    public void setStaChartstatusChrt(String staChartstatusChrt) {
        this.staChartstatusChrt = staChartstatusChrt;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CHARTS_ID")
    public Long getChartsId() {
        return chartsId;
    }

    public void setChartsId(Long chartsId) {
        this.chartsId = chartsId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ORGS_ORGS_ID")
    public Long getOrgsOrgsId() {
        return orgsOrgsId;
    }

    public void setOrgsOrgsId(Long orgsOrgsId) {
        this.orgsOrgsId = orgsOrgsId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "TXT_UNITLABLE_CHRT")
    public String getTxtUnitlableChrt() {
        return txtUnitlableChrt;
    }

    public void setTxtUnitlableChrt(String txtUnitlableChrt) {
        this.txtUnitlableChrt = txtUnitlableChrt;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "TXT_POSTLABLE_CHRT")
    public String getTxtPostlableChrt() {
        return txtPostlableChrt;
    }

    public void setTxtPostlableChrt(String txtPostlableChrt) {
        this.txtPostlableChrt = txtPostlableChrt;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "TXT_JOBLABLE_CHRT")
    public String getTxtJoblableChrt() {
        return txtJoblableChrt;
    }

    public void setTxtJoblableChrt(String txtJoblableChrt) {
        this.txtJoblableChrt = txtJoblableChrt;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "FLG_ISPRIMERYA_CHRT")
    public Boolean getFlgIsprimeryaChrt() {
        return flgIsprimeryaChrt;
    }

    public void setFlgIsprimeryaChrt(Boolean flgIsprimeryaChrt) {
        this.flgIsprimeryaChrt = flgIsprimeryaChrt;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "COD_UNITCODE_UNTS")
    public String getCodUnitcodeUnts() {
        return codUnitcodeUnts;
    }

    public void setCodUnitcodeUnts(String codUnitcodeUnts) {
        this.codUnitcodeUnts = codUnitcodeUnts;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "STA_STATUS_UNTS")
    public String getStaStatusUnts() {
        return staStatusUnts;
    }

    public void setStaStatusUnts(String staStatusUnts) {
        this.staStatusUnts = staStatusUnts;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "UNTS_UNITS_ID")
    public Long getUntsUnitsId() {
        return untsUnitsId;
    }

    public void setUntsUnitsId(Long untsUnitsId) {
        this.untsUnitsId = untsUnitsId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CHRT_CHARTS_ID")
    public Long getChrtChartsId() {
        return chrtChartsId;
    }

    public void setChrtChartsId(Long chrtChartsId) {
        this.chrtChartsId = chrtChartsId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DES_UNITDESC_UNTS")
    public String getDesUnitdescUnts() {
        return desUnitdescUnts;
    }

    public void setDesUnitdescUnts(String desUnitdescUnts) {
        this.desUnitdescUnts = desUnitdescUnts;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "UNTY_UNTYPE_ID")
    public Long getUntyUntypeId() {
        return untyUntypeId;
    }

    public void setUntyUntypeId(Long untyUntypeId) {
        this.untyUntypeId = untyUntypeId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DAT_STARTDATE_UNTS")
    public Time getDatStartdateUnts() {
        return datStartdateUnts;
    }

    public void setDatStartdateUnts(Time datStartdateUnts) {
        this.datStartdateUnts = datStartdateUnts;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DAT_ENDDATE_UNTS")
    public Time getDatEnddateUnts() {
        return datEnddateUnts;
    }

    public void setDatEnddateUnts(Time datEnddateUnts) {
        this.datEnddateUnts = datEnddateUnts;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "UNITS_ID")
    public Long getUnitsId() {
        return unitsId;
    }

    public void setUnitsId(Long unitsId) {
        this.unitsId = unitsId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "NAM_LDAPGROUP_UNTS")
    public String getNamLdapgroupUnts() {
        return namLdapgroupUnts;
    }

    public void setNamLdapgroupUnts(String namLdapgroupUnts) {
        this.namLdapgroupUnts = namLdapgroupUnts;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "COD_AREACODE_UNTS")
    public String getCodAreacodeUnts() {
        return codAreacodeUnts;
    }

    public void setCodAreacodeUnts(String codAreacodeUnts) {
        this.codAreacodeUnts = codAreacodeUnts;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "NUM_SORT_UNTS")
    public Long getNumSortUnts() {
        return numSortUnts;
    }

    public void setNumSortUnts(Long numSortUnts) {
        this.numSortUnts = numSortUnts;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DAT_STARTDATE_POST")
    public Time getDatStartdatePost() {
        return datStartdatePost;
    }

    public void setDatStartdatePost(Time datStartdatePost) {
        this.datStartdatePost = datStartdatePost;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DAT_ENDDATE_POST")
    public Time getDatEnddatePost() {
        return datEnddatePost;
    }

    public void setDatEnddatePost(Time datEnddatePost) {
        this.datEnddatePost = datEnddatePost;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "STA_POSTSTATE_POST")
    public String getStaPoststatePost() {
        return staPoststatePost;
    }

    public void setStaPoststatePost(String staPoststatePost) {
        this.staPoststatePost = staPoststatePost;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "JOBS_JOBS_ID")
    public Long getJobsJobsId() {
        return jobsJobsId;
    }

    public void setJobsJobsId(Long jobsJobsId) {
        this.jobsJobsId = jobsJobsId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DES_POSTDESC_POST")
    public String getDesPostdescPost() {
        return desPostdescPost;
    }

    public void setDesPostdescPost(String desPostdescPost) {
        this.desPostdescPost = desPostdescPost;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "COD_POSTCODE_POST")
    public String getCodPostcodePost() {
        return codPostcodePost;
    }

    public void setCodPostcodePost(String codPostcodePost) {
        this.codPostcodePost = codPostcodePost;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "FLG_ISMANAGER_POST")
    public Boolean getFlgIsmanagerPost() {
        return flgIsmanagerPost;
    }

    public void setFlgIsmanagerPost(Boolean flgIsmanagerPost) {
        this.flgIsmanagerPost = flgIsmanagerPost;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "POSTS_ID")
    public Long getPostsId() {
        return postsId;
    }

    public void setPostsId(Long postsId) {
        this.postsId = postsId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "NAM_LDAPGROUP_POST")
    public String getNamLdapgroupPost() {
        return namLdapgroupPost;
    }

    public void setNamLdapgroupPost(String namLdapgroupPost) {
        this.namLdapgroupPost = namLdapgroupPost;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "POST_POSTS_ID")
    public Long getPostPostsId() {
        return postPostsId;
    }

    public void setPostPostsId(Long postPostsId) {
        this.postPostsId = postPostsId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "COD_USERID_PSTME")
    public String getCodUseridPstme() {
        return codUseridPstme;
    }

    public void setCodUseridPstme(String codUseridPstme) {
        this.codUseridPstme = codUseridPstme;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "STA_MEMBERSTATUS_PSTME")
    public String getStaMemberstatusPstme() {
        return staMemberstatusPstme;
    }

    public void setStaMemberstatusPstme(String staMemberstatusPstme) {
        this.staMemberstatusPstme = staMemberstatusPstme;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DAT_STARTDATE_PSTME")
    public Time getDatStartdatePstme() {
        return datStartdatePstme;
    }

    public void setDatStartdatePstme(Time datStartdatePstme) {
        this.datStartdatePstme = datStartdatePstme;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DAT_ENDDATE_PSTME")
    public Time getDatEnddatePstme() {
        return datEnddatePstme;
    }

    public void setDatEnddatePstme(Time datEnddatePstme) {
        this.datEnddatePstme = datEnddatePstme;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "POSTMEM_ID")
    public Long getPostmemId() {
        return postmemId;
    }

    public void setPostmemId(Long postmemId) {
        this.postmemId = postmemId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the entityManager need to refresh and reload the new Entity added!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

The problem was from Database Configuration in apllication.properties file